# How to debug the implicit query executed by Hibernate?

Tags: spring

I get `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` at runtime when the code reaches this line : `session.merge(role);`

So how to show the query text executed during this merge ?

**update :**

here is how I configured the app :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.ambre.pta")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:jdbc.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/global.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/main.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/admin.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/referentiel.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/departement.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/exercice.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/defi.properties")
})
public class ApplicationContextConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {

        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+env.getProperty("jdbc.server")+":"+env.getProperty("jdbc.port")+":"+env.getProperty("jdbc.instance"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.login.default"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.pwd.default"));

        return dataSource;

    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);

        sessionBuilder.scanPackages("com.ambre.pta.model");

        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();

    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);

        return transactionManager;

    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "utilisateurDao")
    public UtilisateurDAO getUtilisateurDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new UtilisateurDAOImpl(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "menuDao")
    public MenuDAO getMenuDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new MenuDAOImpl(sessionFactory);
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Debug means print/view ?

Comment: yes , show the query text in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add the below tag to your hibernate config

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

Comment: do you mean in the `pom.xml` corresponding to the hibernate dependency ?

Comment: How have you configured the hibernate ? Java or XML ? If it is XML , generally there will be a hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: In the pom.xml : `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: Its not in the pom

Comment: there is no `hibernate.cfg.xml` in my project folders.

Comment: Dont you have a hibernate.cfg.xml  in your project ? Where have you configured the connection details ? The mapped wntity details etc ?

Answer (score 1):

look into

1. hibernate config file
2. application.yml file, there might be hibernate configuration and `show-sql: true` option.